# Convert jsonnode to pojo

Tags: java, json, jackson

I can't get the json string that is sent to parse into the pojo.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.sg.info.Account out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1f6dcfe2; line: 1, column: 1]

This is the json

```
[{"accno":9210255,"type":"Stock- and mutual funds account","default":true,"alias":"Karlsson Joachim"}]
```

The parsing

```
public void getAccounts()
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String resp = Login.getBaseResource().path("accounts").request(Login.getResponsetype()).get(String.class);

        try  {

            account = mapper.readValue(resp, Account.class);
```

POJO

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Account {

    public Account() {

    }
    private long accno;
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("default")
    private String isDefault; 
    private String alias;


    public long getAccno() {
        return accno;
    }
    public void setAccno(long accno) {
        this.accno = accno;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }
    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [accno=" + accno + ", type=" + type + ", alias="
                + alias + "]";
    }
    public String isDefault() {
        return isDefault;
    }
    @JsonProperty("default")
    public void setDefault(String isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is the JSON you have is an array, and can have multiple accounts. If you change the parsing code to something like this, it will work:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String str = "[{\"accno\":9210255,\"type\":\"Stock- and mutual funds account\",\"default\":true,\"alias\":\"Karlsson Joachim\"}]";

    JavaType accountListType =  mapper.getTypeFactory().constructArrayType(Account.class);

    Account[] accounts = SharedJsonSerializer.objectMapper().readValue(str, accountListType);
```

Of course it is better to use a collection type, you can construct any type you want using the mapper.getTypeFactory()

Comment: That works, but there is also a lesser well-known nifty short cat for array types: just try `Account[].class` as the type!

Comment: That does work. But I was hoping he will use this method to creatca collection instead... IMHO, always better to use a collection over an array

Comment: Arrays and Collections have their own benefits, I don't see Collections being inherently better, especially so for simple data access objects.